# How add 2 header rows in listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, columnheader

I want to add 2 header rows in list view like below:

```
   | ------------------------------|------------------|
   |        |      Set1            |      Set2        |    
   |--------| -------------------  |   ---------------|  
   | Name   | col1 col2 col3 col4  |   col5  col6 col7|
   | -------|----------------------|------------------|
   | item1  |   i1  i2   i3   i4   |    i5     i6  i7 |
   | item2  |   i8  i9   i10  i11  |    i12    i13 i14| 
   ---------------------------------------------------
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

*ListView* control does not provide functionality for adding multiple header rows out of the box. To add multiple header rows you will need to handle some of *ListView* events or define new events and implement drawing of additional header-row yourself. There are number of examples on customizing appearance of grid and list controls:

- [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4243/Customizing-the-header-control-in-a-ListView) about changing appearance of *ListView* control header
- [Thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/two-row-headers-datagridview-t3708144.html) about adding new header-row to *DataGridView*.